# Can a TextEntry.text with readonly be manipulated by code?

Tags: android, kivy

Like, can an output-only `TextEntry(readonly=True)` be changed with `TextEntry.insert_text()`? Does the readonly refers ONLY to the user part of the  GUI?

Comment: How about just trying it and see what happens...

Comment: I'd have to take a bus to my university to test, because I won't have a computer available until next week...

Comment: In that case you really are entitled to ask a question like that, I hope someone will provide the answer you need in time.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you actually mean `TextInput`. If so, the answer is: no, you cannot change the text in code using `insert_text`, but you can change it using a simple `text=`.

Answer (score 0):

John Anderson has already given an answer.

You can download the Kivy Launcher or QPython from google playstore so that you can test your kivy codes without using a desktop.

Here is a simple code with TextInput using QPython2:

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:2
#qpy:kivy
#qpy:fullscreen

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestingText(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestingText, self).__init__()

        self.size = Window.size

        self.t = TextInput(readonly=True)

        self.b1 = Button(text="Insert")
        self.b2 = Button(text="Set")

        self.t.center = self.center
        self.b2.right = self.right

        self.b1.on_press = self.inserttext
        self.b2.on_press = self.settext

        self.add_widget(self.t)
        self.add_widget(self.b1)
        self.add_widget(self.b2)

    def inserttext(self):
        self.t.insert_text("insertme")

    def settext(self):
        self.t.text = "setme"

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return TestingText()

Test().run()
```